# What does $\operatorname{bb}()$ mean in information theory?

Tags: notation, terminology, information-theory, entropy

I'm coming across a lot of formulas in the textbook that use "bb()" however, I don't know what bb is, it isn't mentioned anywhere.

For example max entropy in a binary source:

$$\mathbb{H}_{max} = \sum_{j=1}^m \frac1m \cdot \operatorname{bb} \frac1{\frac1m} = \operatorname{bb} m$$

What does the $\operatorname{bb}$ mean?

**Edit** here is another formula of entropy:

$$\mathbb{H} = \sum_{j=1}^m P_jS_j = \sum_{j=1}^m P_j \cdot \operatorname{bb} \frac1{P_j}$$

With $S_j =$ auto information.

Comment: What textbook are you using

Comment: It's the teacher's textbook

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem They mean title and author.

Comment: It's a PDF, so I don't think it is published anywhere. Also the PDF doesn't contain any author name or title :/. Let me add another formula, maybe it'll make it easier to find out what the bb is.

Comment: Added another formula, it's the formula for Entropy, so maybe this is easier to know what the bb means?

Comment: Comparing it with formulas here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory) I would guess it has some logarithmic context, but it is hard to tell without seeing the notes. I would suggest looking from the start of your pdf and finding the first time your author uses the term.

Comment: @bburGsamohT The second formula in the post is page 4, the first place where it is used. Doesn't really have any explanation about it. I thought it's some statistical function/naming maybe?

Comment: Looks like binary logarithm to me i.e. $bb(x) = \log_2(x)$ (this is the function that should appear in the formula for entropy).

Comment: Could it be "binary base", the logarithm to base $2$ ?

Comment: I was $4$ seconds too late :)

Comment: Oh you're right!! I remember it now :D Thanks! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$bb(x)=log_2(x)$$ is the "binary base" , the logarithm to base $2$.